# Which Windows SDK is the best for me in C++ Win32?

Tags: c++, sdk, codeblocks, winapi

I need to develop an application that it could run in any version of Windows XP (Service Pack 1, 2 or not SP) or any higher Windows versions (Vista, 7 or 8).

In this application i need to:

1- Connect to a database with maximum record 500,000

2- Connect to HTTP protocol and received data

I'm new in C++ and I'm using code::block compiler.

Which one is the best windows sdk for me in C++ language?

If you have any recommended database for me, please let me know.

Comment: Download the latest SDK, only develop with features from Windows XP, use SQL Server embedded (or whatever they're calling it now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Windows SDK you can find any information on MSDN, you just have to search. But I suggest to use some cross-platform and maybe more specific libraries. For example, for HTTP protocol you can try libcurl. There are lots of examples on their website and it will be easy for you to implement any HTTP feature. For database features (local database) you can use sqlite. It is very powerful, fast and convenient. Both these libraries can be easily added into your app and they will work in any version of Windows.

P.S. To use sqlite you should know some basics of SQL query language but it is not a problem, I think